# at job seems to be running using /bin/sh though I have a #!/bin/bash

Tags: bash, at

I am trying to run a job using `at`, and I have a `bash` script (I do have `#!/bin/bash` as the first line), but the job fails because of use of `[[` and `]]` in the script, I see the following in the `mail` that it generates:

```
=sh: 58: [[: not found
=sh: 58: [[: not found
=sh: 58: [[: not found
=sh: 58: [[: not found
=sh: 58: [[: not found
```

The `/bin/sh` is a link to `dash`, but if I have the she-bang line as `#!/bin/bash` in my script - should it not use `bash` instead?

P.S If I just run the script on my `bash` prompt - it works fine with no errors (and it has executable permissions).

--EDIT--

I am adding the job like this:

```
$ at 1:30 am today -f /path/to/my/script.sh



$ which bash 
/bin/bash

$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 30  2012 /bin/sh -> dash

$ uname -a
Linux server1 3.5.0-46-generic #70~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 9 23:55:12 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can you add to question the `at` command that you type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POSIX defined that [at](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/at.html#tag_20_05_06) can use [SHELL](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/at.html#tag_20_05_08) environment variable as alternative to `/bin/sh`, but did not restrict it:

> SHELL
>
> Determine a name of a command interpreter to be used to invoke the
>   at-job. If the variable is unset or null, sh shall be used. If it is
>   set to a value other than a name for sh, the implementation shall do
>   one of the following: use that shell; use sh; use the login shell from
>   the user database; or any of the preceding accompanied by a warning
>   diagnostic about which was chosen.

Some implementation of at can give you ability to chose which shell you want to run, like `-k` for Korn shell, `-c` for C-shell. And not all implementation of `at` allow `SHELL` to substitute `sh`. So POSIX also guaranteed the reliable way to use another shell is [explicit call it](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/at.html#tag_20_05_16):

> Some implementations do not allow substitution of different shells
>   using SHELL. System V systems, for example, have used the login shell
>   value for the user in /etc/passwd. To select reliably another command
>   interpreter, the user must include it as part of the script, such as:
>
> $ at 1800
>
> myshell myscript
>
> EOT
>
> job ... at ... $

A simple way, using `bash` to run your script is passing `bash script` as stdin to `at`:

```
echo "bash /path/to/yourscript" | at <time>
```

Example:

```
echo "bash /path/to/yourscript" | at 16:30
```

will run `bash /path/to/yourscript` at 16:30 today.

Comment: This worked!, but somehow, I am not getting a mail - at the end of the script, I have a `mutt` invocation to send out a mail to me, I have also configured `postfix`, but apart from that - the script execution seems to be done.

Comment: oops! the mail was sent, OL moved it to junk! :(. sorry.

Answer (score 4):

[`at`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at) and [`batch`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_1.1.0/gLSB/batch.html):

> read commands from standard  input  or  a  specified  file which are to be executed at a later time, using /bin/sh.

[POSIX defines `at`'s input](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/at.html#tag_20_05_06) as:

> a text file consisting of commands acceptable to the shell command language described in [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18).

That is, it's *required* to be a POSIX `sh` script. Bash allows Bashisms through even when it's run as `sh`, but `dash` is strict. The script isn't run as an executable, but directly with `sh`, so an arbitrary binary or a Python script won't work either, for example.

---

What you may be able to do, though, is to force yourself into `bash` anyway. Something like:

```
[ "$BASH_VERSION" ] || exec bash "/path/to/script"
```

at the top of the file should have the script re-execute itself with `bash` when it isn't already being interpreted that way. The shell won't generate syntax errors for code it that execution doesn't get to, so the later uses of `[[` won't matter. You may be able to use `$0` instead of the path, but it seems to be inconsistent across `at` implementations and none of the specifications imply it should work, so the path will be more reliable.

Comment: OMG! I have to _force_ re-execute in `bash`!, I could have never imagined that method! I'll try it now.

Comment: I added `[ $BASH_VERSION ] || exec /bin/bash "$0"` as the first line in my script, but in the mail, I see this error `/bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file`, not sure why!

Answer (score 2):

My answer is similar to Gnouc’s, but I believe I have a better explanation of the “Why?” 
When you say `at … -f /path/to/my/script.sh`,
you are telling `at` to read `/path/to/my/script.sh`. 
It copies your script somewhere (probably somewhere under `/var/spool/cron`)
so that `atd`, the `at` jobs daemon, can pass the script’s contents to `/bin/sh`. 
At this point, the `#!/bin/bash` she-bang line is just a comment,
and your `[[…]]` usage is an error.

What you want to do is not give `at` the *contents* of your script,
but give it the *name*, by

```
$ echo /path/to/my/script.sh | at 1:30 am today
```

or

```
$ at 1:30 am today
/path/to/my/script.sh
Ctrl+D
```

That way, the `/bin/sh` will see `/path/to/my/script.sh`
and will execute it as a command. 
And *then* the she-bang line will do its job, causing `bash` to be invoked.

P.S. My answer (like Gnouc’s) has the “feature” that,
if you change your script between now and 1:30 am today,
`atd` will run the modified version. 
(This is in contrast to your approach, using `-f`,
where `at` makes a copy of your script when you run `at`.) 
In particular, if you delete or rename the script, nothing will run.

Comment: I think `cron` is not issue here. Some implementation of `at` can give you ability to chose which shell you want to run, like `-k` for Korn shell, `-c` for C-shell.

Comment: @Gnouc: I don’t understand what your point is. `cron` is the daemon that runs `at` jobs, so your answer is all about what shell `cron` uses (you just don’t say that you’re talking about `cron`). And your statement about `at` looks like it should maybe be a part of *your* answer.

Comment: `at` jobs queue is run by `atd` daemon. Nothing about `cron` here. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Gnouc: OK, I updated my answer.